Force reapproval of Google prompt when using Auth0 universal login
I'm using Auth0 as the IDP of a .NET 8 application to let the users sign in via Google.
I have managed to get the Google access and refresh tokens for the user from Auth0, but sometimes I need to force the user to re-approve the Google consent screen in order to get a new refresh token.
I had the exact same setup in an older Auth0 tenant, but I've recently created a new one and it seems doesn't work the same way, or I've forgot to enable something at Auth0.
This is the code and the expected behavior is that the user is redirected to the Google consent screen when approval_prompt=force is added to the auth parameters, but the actual behavior is that the user is redirected to Auth0 and then directly back to my application.
The code:
    private static ChallengeHttpResult Handle(bool? forceApprovalPrompt, string? returnUrl)
    {
        var authenticationPropertiesBuilder = new LoginAuthenticationPropertiesBuilder()
            .WithParameter("connection_scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly")
            .WithParameter("access_type", "offline")
            .WithRedirectUri(returnUrl);

        if (forceApprovalPrompt is true)
        {
            authenticationPropertiesBuilder.WithParameter("approval_prompt", "force");
        }

        return TypedResults.Challenge(authenticationPropertiesBuilder.Build(), [Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme]);
    }

And this is the resulting URL the user is redirected to:
https://<...>.eu.auth0.com/authorize?client_id=<...>&redirect_uri=https://<...>/signin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid profile email offline&response_mode=form_post&nonce=<...>&auth0Client=<...>&connection_scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&state=<...>&x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&x-client-ver=7.1.2.0

